# Send a message on Facebook using jQuery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I've been hammering at this for days and can't figure it out. Trying to use jQuery / Javascript to type a message in the box of a Facebook chat and then hit Send.

It looks like there's a span element which displays the entered text, but if that element is modified, the text is reset upon clicking on the box. I can't find the input text stored anywhere (searched the DOM, all Javascript variables, even tried searching for the text uuencoded etc.)
Standard methods of typing (triggering the keydown event) don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: prefilling is not allowed.

Comment: Facebook has gone to a certain amount of effort to block attempts to automate its UI in potentially malicious ways (such as sending chats without the user's involvement.)  A correct answer to this question would likely be eligible for a bug bounty https://www.facebook.com/whitehat

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of forbidden by FB policy. So, my answer - just you can't do this. They give wrights to send message only for users.